# Makefile error : make (e=2) The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, mingw, sfml

I'm trying to call the clean part of this makefile, but it keeps throwing the error in the title.
This is what it looks like. What could be possible fixes for this. I'm using this makefile to get SFML up and running.

```
clean:
    rm -f main *.o
```

The code is supposed to remove the main.exe and main.o files but it just throws that error.

Comment: You can only leave out the ".exe" when running the executable; in all other cases you need to use its full name.

Comment: @molbdnilo I included the ".exe" and it still throws the same error. What could be causing this?

Comment: The error message sounds like the culprit is `rm` or `make`. Are you running this in an msys shell?

Comment: @molbdnilo This is in VSCode. I'm trying to set up SFML. I should add that I am following a tutorial for this setup but i can't get past this step.

Comment: @molbdnilo Update, It works when I use 'del' instead of 'rm'.

Comment: `rm` is a POSIX command.  If you are running on Windows and make is invoking `cmd.exe` as your shell, then you don't have POSIX commands available to you (unless you installed them and modified your PATH to add the directory where they're installed).  If you are running on Windows you of course have to use Windows commands, not POSIX commands (you would use POSIX commands on GNU/Linux or MacOS).

Comment: There are bash shells and other terminals that work on MS Windows. I recommend using [msys2 to install MinGW](https://www.msys2.org/#installation) and use one of its [terminals](https://www.msys2.org/docs/terminals/).